# Node array toString Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, tostring

I have a method which returns children of a given Node. All thats inside a Node (instance variable) is a  char character.

```
 public Node[] children(){

    return (Node[]) children.toArray(new Node [children.size()]);
 }
```

I want to output those children later. But it only outputs the reference [Lie.gmit.Node;@7d487b8b]. How would I override the toString method ? or should I create a new method for outputing children nodes ?

Comment: What programming language is this written in?

Comment: that language is java

Comment: `@Override
public String toString() {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `toString` method of Node class. E.g.

```
public class MyNode extends Node {

@Override
public String toString() {
    //your code here
}

}
```

It is possible that you need to implement some more code (I don't know is Node your custom implementation or some library).

After that, you can print it using the [Arrays.deepToString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) method:

```
MyNode[] children = someNode.children();
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(children));
```

UPDATE:

If you implemented the `Node` class, then there is no need for extending it, just add the `toString` method to your `Node` class.